# How do I obtain the path towards the macro using the macro (vba code) itself?

Tags: vba, outlook

Note: I am not interested in finding the path towards the worksheet, I intend to write the path to the worksheet in a text file that is located in the same folder as the .OTM file.
I need to transform this code from hardcoded path to a path read from a text file located in the same folder as the macro.

How do I obtain the path towards the macro using the macro (vba code) itself?

```
Public xlApp As Object
Public xlWB As Object
Public xlSheet As Object
Sub OpenXl()
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test2.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Process the message record
    On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Find the property that tells you were the excel file is. First google reponse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba 2. Change `strPath` to refer to that instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the path of current worksheet in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba)

Comment: I'm not interested in finding the path to the workbook, I'm interested in finding the path to the macro, so I know where to read my text file from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OTM file is stored here on my PC (Windows 7/Outlook 2010):

```
strPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\"
```

Comment: Yes, but is there no way to find the path using ol vba script? Say I have it in a folder located on my desktop, and then I move the folder in my documents or something.

Comment: I was looking into that.  As far as I can tell it's pretty much got to be in that folder for that version otherwise it doesn't work.  From Sue Moshers old page:  _All Outlook macros are stored in a single file named VbaProject.otm in the user's %appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook folder_  http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28

Comment: So the macro simply doesn't work if it's not stored in said folder?

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  I did find some posts saying you could use a switch when opening Outlook but it had been deprecated in 2010 (/altvba).  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c64af38f-f333-4da0-ae9f-6e866ac58efc/moving-vbaprojectotm?forum=outlookdev

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Path
```

This returns the path of the workbook containing the code.

Comment: I use outlook vba, so when I try to `debug.print thisworkbook.path` it gives me an Object required error.

Comment: It does however return the appropriate path towards the workbook when i use `debug.print xlWB.Path`, but that is of no help to me.

Comment: Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233702/where-does-outlook-store-the-vba-code-files, it appears Outlook code is stored in the users `%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook` folder. What path are you trying to get?

Comment: Say I move the .OTM to another folder, is there no way for me to use vba script to tell where it's located?