# Export a Outlook form written in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

I recently wrote a form in VBA for Outlook and saved it to my personal form folder.

Now this form should get exported in a userfriendly fashion. What is the best practise here?

I know that you can go to **File -> Export file...** in VBA, but this seems to have caused some problems in the past and doesn't seem very intuitive to use both the frm and the frx files.

The form is supposed to be accessed by employees to book their holiday.

Comment: Why not just share the project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233702/where-does-outlook-store-the-vba-code-files#:~:text=All%20Outlook%20macros%20are%20stored,hidden%20folder%20on%20most%20systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is COM add-ins were invented for. They are designed to be installed on multiple machines and users. VBA macros are not designed for transferring the code - the infrastructure doesn't provide anything for moving solutions automatically like you could do in case of COM add-ins. You need have do that manually in VBA.

If you consider moving your solution to the add-in rails, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) to get started quickly. You may choose VB.NET which has a similar syntax with VBA.